# What is the best way to position div for mobile purpose viewing?

Tags: css

I have a issue whereby images that are I div because of the style percentage width property will get resize weirdly and will not display correcty in pc or mobile iPhone

What is the best way to position div for mobile purpose viewing

Percentage or there are other alternative?

Taking into consideration tat the image may be resize

Comment: This entirely depends on what you are trying to display.  Perhaps a different layout would be better.

Comment: @ fndf : Hope this blog will help you   http://mobile-web-html.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you will want to use relative widths (percentage or em based), because they scale far better than fixed width items.

Does the same thing occur when you view your website on a browser that has been sized very small? (Especially web-kit browsers)

As has already been mentioned, [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) code is an excellent start to cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Percentages are probably the best way. I use the [Foundation template](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which essentially allows nested grids. That is to say, a top level grid would be the maximum width and if you nest one in side four columns, twelve columns would be equivalent to the maximum width (the four columns).

EDIT: Please note that in this case, the maximum size is specified in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try validating your site against an xhtml validator like the one at w3schools.com.  If it passes the validator, there's a decent chance that it'll display pretty consistently in whichever browser you use.

[w3schools Validators](http://www.w3schools.com/site/site_validate.asp)

Comment: It's not any official guideline and you might consider it personal taste / opinion - but please do  not recommend or link to w3schools. It's full of misinformation and does not deserve it's place in search engine results. See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) for reference. As for markup validation, use the official [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) from the _W3C_ instead, for instance.